# storing different rows of two lists in new list

Tags: list, compare, row

I am trying to create a new object by comparing two list. If the rows are matching the row should be removed form the splitted row_list or appended to a new list containing only the differences between both lists.
Sample data: basically the data is structured in a way that splitted_row_list has all the rows all_rows has, but contains additional rows, which are different, aswell(btw also meaning there is an unequal amount of rows between both lists) . I am amining to do put these additional rows into a new object.

```
all_rows[0]:'1390', '139080', '13980', '1380', '139080', '13080'
splitted_row_list[0]:'35335','53527','353529','242424','5222','444'


results = []
for row in splitted_row_list:
    print(row)
    for row1 in all_rows:
        if row1 == row:
            
            splitted_row_list.remove(row)
        else:
            results.append(row)





print(results)
```

However, this code just returns all the rows. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The two lists are distict, therefore you get every item in one list because `if row1 == row` is never true, then you wont remove anything.
There are no differences.

EDIT:
You can simply

```py
nonunique = []
for row in splitted_row_list:
    print(row)
    for row1 in all_rows:
        if row1 == row:
            nonunique.append(splitted_row_list.remove(row))

result = splitted_row_list #the nonunique have been removed
```

if you want the non unique from all_rows, just add a `all_rows.remove(row)`.
For the complete sets, just concatenate them after the loop.
`all = nonunique +splitted_row_list+all_rows`

Comment: The example i demonstrated shows two different rows, However row1 == row, is true for about 60 percent of the cases, which it properly executes, which i noticed by a print statement not included here...

Comment: Taking a closer look, this code doesn't makes much sense. The problem is that you are appending every result bot the one that is equal to the if statement, for every item in row,  which negates the effect, for exemple: a=[2,3,1] ,b= [4,2,3], when you loop for a[1], you will get the expected result, bust since you are appending all the different from a[2], a[1] will be added to the result list

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have 'solved' this problem in this particular context by just appending a string and then later sorting based on whether they contain the string or not..not very elegant but it works..

```
def append_mark2(splitted_row_list):

for row in splitted_row_list:

    for row1 in all_rows:
        if row1 == row:

            row.append('jaja')
            print(row)
return splitted_row_list

def sort_on_appendix(splitted_row_list_appended_mark):
next_row_list3=[]
for row in splitted_row_list_appended_mark:
    if 'jaja' not in row:
        print(row)
        next_row_list3.append(row)
print('next_row_list3:',next_row_list3)
return next_row_list3
```